# Passing Data to Label in different View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I have phone number textfield in LoginViewController and I would like to pass entered data to the different controller which is VerifyViewController to be shown into the label. Note: I do not want to use segue, I know there is a way by writing perform segue but do not want that.

Any idea?

[image: 2]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your value to `UserDefaults` :

To save :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(reveivedPhoneNumber, forKey: "labelText")
```

To get :

At your `VerifyViewController` :

```
var labelValue =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "labelText")


yourLabel.text = self.labelValue //at `viewDidLoad` or wherever you want
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to `VerifyViewController` from `LoginViewController` and pass data, here is the code:

```swift
func navigateToVerifyViewController() {
    let verifyViewController = VerifyViewController()
    verifyViewController.enteredPhoneNumberLabel.text = "<Your number>"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(verifyViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Note: This would only work if your `LoginViewController` is in a Navigational Stack. Otherwise use the below code instead of the last line of the above code:

```swift
present(verifyViewController, animated: true)
```